# C++ : Is adding an reference/alias (&) on a left hand const assignment redundant?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, variable-assignment, lvalue

Is a const assignment in C++ implicitly done by reference? If so, is it redundant to make the aliasing explicit, for example:

```
const std::vector<unsigned>& chart = chartData.at(id);
```

i.e. is this equivalent to simply:

```
const std::vector<unsigned> chart = chartData.at(id);
```

Comment: No, one creates a reference, and the other doesn't.

Comment: Why wouldn't the compiler optimize the assignment as a reference since it's a const? There should be nothing that could be done to chart that would mutate chartData.at(id)

Comment: There is no "assignment" in your code.

Comment: could you elaborate? how is the = not an assignment?

Comment: @daj You can only optimise if the semantic of the code remains unchanged. Your proposed “optimisation” (which isn’t even necessarily one) changes the meaning of the code big time.

Comment: I see. I didn't mean to propose some sort of clever optimization, it just hadn't occurred to me why they are different. The examples in the answers make things obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two pieces of code are not the same. Consider:

```
int value{1};
int const& a{value};
int const b{value};

++value;
std::cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n';
```

[<kbd>Running code</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76e7ac545551589f)

Surely we can agree that this is unacceptable for an “optimisation”?

What’s more, the access via a reference can be less efficient than access to a value since the reference will under some circumstances incur an additional dereference operation.

Answer (score 2):

Let us try to understand what you are saying with an example

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int value = 10;
    const int& char1 = value;
    const int chart2 = value;
    cout << "value =" << value << " char1 =" << char1 << " chart2 =" <<chart2 << endl;

    value++;

    cout << "value =" << value << " char1 =" << char1 << " chart2 =" <<chart2 << endl;

 }
```

Output

```
value =10 char1 =10 chart2 =10
value =11 char1 =11 chart2 =10
```

So as you can see **const int& char1** creates a reference  and any subsequent change in the referenced value would be seen by the char1.

Whereas **const int char2** creates a copy and would retain the value that was assigned.

Comment: What about in the context of a function parameter in a single threaded application?